# updateTextView(), show the name of the current user android eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have problem with the updateTextView, like when you login to main activity, then it will go to the next activity which I named as homepage/about. there is a "Welcome" textview and on the right side of it is should be the name of the current user.like "Welcome User"

I tried it with the updateTextView but I have a errors. please help me.

here is the homepage.java code:

```
    package com.example.howtos;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
//import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class homepage extends Activity {

private TextView textView;
private DatabaseManager dataBase;
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "users";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "real_name";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.homepage);

  //get the connection on the 
    DatabaseManager dataBase = DatabaseManager.instance();

  //get the id of the textview to show text
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    Button a = (Button) findViewById (R.id.next1);
    a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override    public void onClick(View v) {
     startActivity(new Intent(homepage.this,need.class)); 
        }
});
    Button out = (Button) findViewById (R.id.lo);
    out.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override    public void onClick(View v) {
     startActivity(new Intent(homepage.this,MainActivity.class)); 
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logout Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });


    updateTextView();   
}

    public void updateTextView() {

    //get all the available values from the database
        Cursor cursor = dataBase.select("SELECT real_name FROM " + TABLE_NAME);

        textView.setText("");

        while(cursor.moveToNext()) {

        //put the values fetched from the database to the textview
        String s = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME));
        textView.append("\n" + s);
        }


        cursor.close();
        //----->



    }  
}
```

and my logcat:

```
    10-17 23:38:34.451: E/AndroidRuntime(644): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-17 23:38:34.451: E/AndroidRuntime(644): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to    start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.howtos/com.example.howtos.homepage}:   java.lang.NullPointerException
10-17 23:38:34.451: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
10-17 23:38:34.451: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at  android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
10-17 23:38:34.451: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access    $600(ActivityThread.java:123)
10-17 23:38:34.451: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at android.app.ActivityThread   $H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
10-17 23:38:34.451: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage   (Handler.java:99)
10-17 23:38:34.451: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at android.os.Looper.loop   (Looper.java:137)
10-17 23:38:34.451: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main  (ActivityThread.java:4424)
10-17 23:38:34.451: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-17 23:38:34.451: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke  (Method.java:511)
10-17 23:38:34.451: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit   $MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-17 23:38:34.451: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-17 23:38:34.451: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main   (Native Method)
10-17 23:38:34.451: E/AndroidRuntime(644): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-17 23:38:34.451: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at  com.example.howtos.homepage.updateTextView(homepage.java:54)
10-17 23:38:34.451: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at  com.example.howtos.homepage.onCreate(homepage.java:48)
10-17 23:38:34.451: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate   (Activity.java:4465)
10-17 23:38:34.451: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at  android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
10-17 23:38:34.451: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
10-17 23:38:34.451: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in onCreate(), you're redefining dataBase as DataBaseManager which defines it locally rather than globally. Change this line

```
DatabaseManager dataBase = DatabaseManager.instance();
```

to this:

```
dataBase = DatabaseManager.instance();
```

Comment: Thank you ver much sir! :D
but it shows all the names of the users that are registered in the database. can I make it that only the user who logged in show it's name only? not all the names in the database.

Comment: You'll have to add something to your database query that defines only a single user e.g. "SELECT real_name FROM " + TABLE_NAME + "WHERE id = " + user_id
or something like that

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to figure this out.

Comment: Best of luck! If you're not super familiar with mysql queries, they're good to learn :)